Adding new field in a data model for existing flutter app with cloud_firestore as database
In my live flutter app with firebase fire-store database, I have a data model say Product.dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Product{
  final String name;
  final double price;

  Product({required this.name, required this.price});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      "name": name,
      "price": price
    };
  }

  factory Product.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Product(
      name: json["name"],
      price: double.parse(json["price"].toString())
    );
  }

  factory Product.fromRawJson(String str) => Product.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  String toRawJson() => json.encode(toMap());
}

Now, to introduce a new required field for this data model say 'size'. How should we re-write data model class, specifically fromMap() function because Database would not have this field, at least not in all documents even if some are updated using below code in appropriate place in my app.
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('product').doc(id)
    .update({'size': prodSize})
    .then((value) => print("Product Spec Updated"))
    .catchError((error) => print("Failed to update product: $error")); 

Something like below psuedocode is required:
  factory Product.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Product(
      name: json["name"],
      price: double.parse(json["price"].toString())
      size: json.containsKey('size') ? json["size"] : 'not known'
    );
  }


There's answer in my question ;) It wasn't working earlier with some error not related to this. I confirm containsKey() works.

size: json.containsKey('size') ? json["size"] : 'not known'

Above code works to check if a document read from firestore contains the field or not.
